# Linear Simultaneous Equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The first problem of Hardy's Introduction to Pure Mathematics:

What are the conditions that $ax + by + cz = 0$,

(1) for all values of $x,y,z$

(2) for all values of $x,y,z$ subject to condition that $dx + ey + fz = 0$

(3) for all values of $x,y,z$ subject to condition that $dx + ey + fz = 0 $ and $Ax + By + Cz = 0$.

for (1) it must be that $a = b = c = 0$. since otherwise we can choose a value of $x,y,z$ such that $ax + by + cz\neq 0$

for (2) it seems (for the same reason) that the condition must be that 
$a - d = 0, b - e = 0$, and $c - f = 0$.

for (3) it seems that the condition must be that $a - d - A = 0, 
b - e - B = 0, c - f - C = 0$.

Is this correct? It seems too simple and I worry I'm missing the point of the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For 1), it's correct.

For 2), is is the same as : $dx+ey+fz=0\implies ax+by+cz=0$, and is equivalent to $$ \text{the matrices }\;\begin{bmatrix}d&a\\ e&b\\f&c\end{bmatrix}\;\text{and}\;\begin{bmatrix}\strut d\\e\\f\end{bmatrix} \;\text{ have the same rank.}$$

For 3), it is similarly equivalent to$$ \text{the matrices }\;\begin{bmatrix}d&A&a\\ e&B&b\\ f&C&c\end{bmatrix}\;\text{and}\;\begin{bmatrix}\strut d&A\\e&B\\f&C\end{bmatrix} \;\text{ have the same rank.}$$

Comment: so for 2) the condition is that [a, b, c] is a scalar multiple of [d, e, f],

and for 3) the condition is that [a, b, c] is a linear combination of [d, e, f] and [A, B, C]?

Comment: I has to belong to the subspace spanned by these column vectors. Note its the same as the compatibility criterion for the solutions of a non-homogeneous linear system, in terms of  rank of the `completed matrix`.

Comment: How did you realize the problem asked was equivalent to those matricies having the same rank? For example how is: 
dx+ey+fz=0⟹ax+by+cz=0 equivalent to those 2 matricies having the same rank?

Comment: @trynalearn: Well,  consider, say, the 2nd  case, and suppose the smaller matrix has maximum rank (2). The larger matrix then has rank $\ge 2$. If it has rank $2$ it means the  3rd column is linearly dependent on the 1st two, i.e. the corresponding equation is a linear combination of the first two corresponding equations. Is that clear?

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

The equation

$$ax + by + cz = 0$$

represent a plane in $\mathbb{R^3}$.

Comment: So the condition dx + ey + fz = 0 is that (x,y,z) lie on the plane given by the linear equation.

And so for ax + by + cz to equal 0 on those points, isn't that saying that ax + by + cz is the same plane as dx + ey + fz? So this means that a = d, b = e, and c = f right?

Comment: @trynalearn not equals but $a=\lambda d,b=\lambda e,c=\lambda f$ as Bernard explained by rank concept

Comment: Yup just got it!